# In X: Beyond the Frontier, how do I sell my weapons so I can get better ones?

Tags: x-beyond-the-frontier

I cannot buy better weapons anywhere because my two laser slots are full, and I can't figure out where to sell my lasers to free some space.

How do I free up these slots to get new weapons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sell weapon equipment at the equipment docks.  They look like this:

[image]